# Delete files from pushed code on github

Tags: git, github, open-source

I have committed and pushed my changes to my forked copy of a project. Also I have raised a pull request to the repository from which I initially forked the project. Now I have to delete a file which I committed. How should I do it?

Comment: You can rewrite the commit locally and then force push the new version to your own repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file only exists in the last commit, you can simply delete it, amend your commit and use `git push --force` to rewrite the commit on github:

```
git rm file-to-delete

git commit --amend

git push --force
```

If you want to delete the file from several previous commits, take a look at the [github guide](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/) on this subject.

In particular, you can use the [BFG cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to delete files from a repo including all commits history:

```
bfg --delete-files file-to-be-deleted
```

Another alternative which doesn't require installing anything on top of git is the `git filter-branch` command:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file-to-be-deleted' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

After the changes are made locally, you must use `git push --force` to push them to github.

In any case, you should add the file to your `.gitignore` so you don't accidentally commit it again in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It worked great, except that I had a closed pull request on the branch which I could not reopen after the forced pushed. Something to watch out for I guess.